# I need help creating JavaScript validation for my price box

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaSript so I am still learning :). What I have so far is that I can just allow the users to enter in numbers. But how can I change it to:

1. The first number must be >= 1
2. Allow one decimal point and only 2 numbers can be entered after it?

---

```
var isValidPrice = function(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;

        var excludedKey = (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90); 

        if (!excludedKey) {
            return;
        } else {
            return evt.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    input = $('input');

input.on('keydown', function(event) {
    isNumberKey(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex like here:

```
<body>
  <input type="number" id="input" />
  <p id="valid"></p>

  <script>
    var input = $('#input');
    var valid = $('#valid');
    var patt = new RegExp("^\\d\\d\\.\\d\\d$");
    input.on('keyup', function(event) {
      var val = $(this).val();
      if (patt.test(val)){
        valid.text("Valid");
      }
      else{
        valid.text("Not Valid");
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>
```